# Audio Recording on the Web Without Flash

Tags: audio, google-chrome, web

Any plans on Chrome or anyone else supporting this?  I'd rather not build something in Flash if we can avoid it.  I wouldn't mind trying to add it to Chrome or something myself if need be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in Chrome Canary... Finally!  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112367

Answer (score 2):

Ericcson labs is working in an API for this:

https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/

However, it hasn't became true. At the moment, you have no choice but using a plug-in (e.g. Flash) for audio recording.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Recorder.JS](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) to record from any [Web Audio API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/) node including [getUserMedia](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) and microphone input.